# Images not Rendering on IIS7 Running ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net-mvc

The site `63.208.1.26/FreightRateCentral` is not rendering images.  Chrome reports HTTP 404 for each of them.  This is a fresh install of Windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7.  At first, I thought that it was a .NET framework issues, but I ensured that the application pool is running 4.x.  Then, I checked IIS Request Filtering, but .jpg and .png extensions are not being blocked. The deployed site files are in a subfolder under wwwroot.  What other issues may be causing the site from rendering the images correctly?  Thanks for your help and guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, as Chrome correctly reports, a path issue.

The HTML markup says, for example:

```
<ul class="payment-listing">
                            <li>
                                <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" title="Visa">
                                    <img src="/Content/NewImages/img-visa.png" alt="Visa" width="49" height="29" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" title="Master Card">
                                    <img src="/Content/NewImages/img-master-card.jpg" alt="Master Card" width="49" height="29" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" title="Card">
                                    <img src="/Content/NewImages/img-card.jpg" alt="Card" width="49" height="29" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" title="Discover">
                                    <img src="/Content/NewImages/img-discover.jpg" alt="Discover" width="49" height="29" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

The correct path is `http://63.208.1.26/FreightRateCentral/Content/NewImages/`.  In other words, either take the first slash off the img src tag (`<img src="Content/NewImages/img-master-card.jpg">`) or add the FreightRateCentral directory (`<img src="/FreightRateCentral/Content/NewImages/img-master-card.jpg"`).